# Attaching an Amplifier to 555 timer. Collector Voltage is going haywire

Tags: amplifier, bjt, timer, 555

I'm currently trying to power a Piezoelectric Transducer with an oscillating signal. I am doing this because I want to experiment with "acoustic levitation." The piezoelectric transducer is a 50W 40kHz device. From my understanding, my input power does not have to match this wattage because it is just a maximum power spec.

To produce this oscillating signal, I am using a 555 timer with a transistor at its output so the current is high enough to power a transformer to step up the voltage; to provide a power sufficient enough to turn the transducer on.

I am doing everything step by step so I can make sure everything is working properly and right now I am stuck at amplifying the current from the output.

This is my circuit right now. [image: Schematic]
I planned on having the transformer connected to the collector, which is why I put a 1k resistor there as a 'place-mat'

The problem lies in the voltage and current timing diagrams. The collector voltage and current waveforms are going crazy meanwhile the base and emitter mimic the square wave perfectly and I can't understand why.

Does anybody have any idea why?
[image: Voltage Levels]
[image: Current Levels]

Comment: Why would you want to drive a transformer with a collector (current sink or saturated switch) and an average DC voltage of Vcc/2?  What LC self-resonance f and Q do you expect? when the transistor is not conducting current?

Comment: This is my first time creating a circuit like this on my own and I'm just going based off what I remember learning from Electronics I in school where we always used the collector to step up the voltage. It seems that I need to review my notes. My basis of thinking was that the base should be half of the source voltage to bias it properly. No?

Comment: @Dave It's not an appropriate design for use with driving a transformer. Besides, you've not specified any details yet, either. No idea what you want to actually achieve in terms of power (though I know you think the 555 isn't enough to handle it.) You should write more about your ACTUAL goals in the end, so that you can get some more useful help. You are asking for help for one thing, when you really need help for something else (which may, or may not, look like what you imagine right now -- probably at least somewhat different, though.) You probably want a center-tapped primary, at a guess.

Comment: The ridiculously high base and emitter currents are an artefact of the base resistor being far too low.

Comment: @jonk thank you for the reply. I edited my post to provide more detail. The ultimate goal is to get the transducer to vibrate at a high frequency of my choice. I will be adding a POT to 555 so I can adjust the frequency. I just didn't add it to the circuit because its just something I can add on my own when I make sure everything is actually working properly. I'm starting to have the feeling that I need to take the textbook out and actually reexamine how I am going about achieving my goals. Is there any keywords you can advise me to look up to appropriately drive a transformer?

Comment: @Dave Is this a special kind of piezo transducer? Or just a buzzer type? I ask because I don't understand why you need a higher voltage and I want to know what kind of voltage is needed and what kind of power will be needed by the transducer -- it may be driving sound in water or syrup, for all I know... and that matters. If a transformer and 555 really is in your future (and I can't tell), then you will need to center-tap the primary to keep this easy and perhaps to use 40% one side, 40% other side driving, which requires some added stuff. What transducer, what medium is it driving?

Comment: [Ebay Piezo Transducer Link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/50W-40KHz-Ultrasonic-Piezoelectric-Transducer-Cleaner-for-Cleaning-Medical-/151314160291?hash=item233b06daa3:g:qikAAOSwB-1YwXkK) It's this one - a buzzer type. I'm assuming I need a higher voltage so i can get a higher volume to create areas of higher pressure. It's not going to be in water or syrup or anything like that. It's going to be in open space with an adjustable plate on top so I can create standing waves for the levitation. Thank you very much @jonk I appreciate the help tremendously

Comment: [Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qy1w6rTpC2g&t=753s) The end product will be similar to this

Comment: @Dave That is really cool!! Any datasheet on that thing?

Comment: @jonk Unfortunately I do not, the only info i can find is what's on the selling page which is 

Static capacitance: 3500-3800 pF
Insulation Resistance: 10000 Megohm
Frequency: 40KHz
Power: 50W

Comment: @Dave I've found a little more. Something like between \$10-20\:\Omega\$ ohmic resistance. It's important to know because this relates to the voltage required to deliver the indicated power. The peak voltage needs to be about \$V_{peak}=\sqrt{2\cdot R\cdot P}\$. Or \$V_{PP}\approx 80\:\textrm{V}\$ for \$40\:\textrm{W}\$ and \$20\:\Omega\$.

Comment: @jonk So, the equivalent resistance of this transducer is 10-20 Ω which you used to plug into the formula, which tells us what the peak voltage should be. And from there, I pick a transformer and find out what the current level should be going into it to create the peak voltage that I need. And when I find this value out, then I can create my amplifier circuit based off of my findings? Thank you so much, that helped me tremendously. 

It doesn't necessarily have to be 40W though, correct? That is just the maximum power that is allowed through the transducer?

Comment: @Dave Well, the capacitance is another factor. But assuming it's parallel, at the frequency given it isn't that important. So I ignored it. No, it doesn't have to be 40 W. If you can bootstrap things and slug a capacitor around, you could even use the 12 V supply to deliver perhaps 3 W (or more depending on the actual load, if I was anywhere near right about it.) No transformer, at all, then. If using a transformer, I'd probably prefer to use a center-tapped transformer in a push-pull arrangement. But that adds complication and I don't think you are ready for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a simulation artifact.

What simulator are you using?  Are there any configuration parameters such as minimum time step that can be changed? Or selecting a different solver maybe?

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I am using Multisim so I can change the minimum time step. Do you think it is too small so its "grabbing too much noise" causing it to go haywire? I'm sorry but what do you mean by selecting a different solver?

Comment: Often unexpected results occur if the time-step is too coarse rather than too fine, but a fine time step increases the simulation time. With some other simulation programs they have an option to use different methods to solve the equations in the simulation - they can give different results in some situations.  Multisim may not.

Comment: @Dave The simulator is probably working with an infinite rise time on the 555. That will turn into ringing in the rest of it. If you can adjust the rise time do so. If not, add a small cap from the base to ground of Q1. 1nF or so. It wont hurt the design either.

Comment: @Dave You will also need a flyback diode across that transformer.

Comment: @Trevor - you must not have a flyback diode or you will clamp the wanted signal.  You may need another winding on the transformer with a diode back to the supply to reset the magnetic flux.

Comment: @KevinWhite , Indeed, But I was not going that far, not trying to read him mind on where he is headed. Just saying the transistor wont last long as indicated.